# How to access sql database from website?

Tags: mysql, delphi

How to access sql database which is at e.g

```
http://localhost/test.php?blah/blah/blah.sql
```

or Online using ADO connection or something?

I use

- PHP Triad (PHP, Apache 1.3.23, MySQL)
- Delphi 7

I've searched google but I did not find anything.

at *. mdb I usually use the following ways.

```
ADOTable1.ConnectionString: = 'Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;' +
                              ' Data Source =' + 
                              ExtractFilePath (Application.ExeName) + 
                              'data.mdb; Persist Security Info = False';
```

My question is the core principal example below:
I took part database layout direction.

e.g:

```
Source = '+ ExtractFilePath (Application.ExeName) +' data.mdb;
```

or

```
Source = 'D: \ Test \ data.mdb';
```

or

```
Source = 'Drive \ Directory \ Filename.Extension';
```

how to change the above example to be.

```
Source = 'http:// localhost/Test/Data.db';
```

and I just want to know how to connect Ado / components that can be used to import data from MySql and then sent to the columns in DBGrid, so I can Add, Edit and delete existing data in MySql table through Delphi.

NB: I do not know the composition of the MySql table, because I usually just use *. Mdb.
- If the PHP script I've encountered a lot of tutorials, but in Delphi not found.

Comment: And what database do you use? Please update your question

Comment: MySQL, The above example is http://myvirtualweb.com/localhost/127.0.0.1 on my PC, because rule writing on editor page asked me to complete the add. com

Comment: Can you please update your question with this important information from your comment?

Comment: Please add information (especially information like what specific SQL database you're using) by making an [edit] to your question and not by adding it to the comments. In this case, you should also add a `mysql` tag while you're editing. Details like this are important to the content of your question, because different SQL servers have very different connection details. Thanks.

Comment: Access MySQL via PHP tunnel http://www.devart.com/mydac/docs/network_tunneling.htm